# In Wagtail how can I access the Page object from inside the StructBlock template?

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I have a page called `Event`
For the event I would like to have a program.
Program consists of ProgramEntry objects linked to the page with ParentalKey.
I would like this program to be displayed in the html, but it should be in a streamfield so that the editors can place it wherever they like in the page.
To do this I would like to render the my custom ProgramEntryBlock that is simply this:

```py
class ProgramEntryBlock(blocks.StructBlock):
    class Meta:
        label = _("Program entry")
        template = "blocks/program-entry-block.html"
```

in my template `blocks/program-entry-block.html` I would like to have something like this:

```
{% if page.program_entries.exists %}
    (...)

    {% for entry in page.program_entries.all %}
        (...)
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

How can I pass the Page object in this template?
Or, what could be a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in [this section of the wagtail documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering) it says we can do this:

```
{% include_block page.body with page=page %}
```

Inside the page template. Just like with django include tag.

This solves my problem but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it.